# How to keep headline and text in the same column using ColumnText?

Tags: layout, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using iText to create a PDF file. While testing, a situation occurred where a headline was printed at the bottom of a column but the appendant text in the next.

The easy solution `paragraph.setKeepTogether( true );` results in to much white space (see additional info below). Here is an image showing the current situation on the left and what I'd like to get on the right:

[current and wanted situation](http://s7.directupload.net/images/130131/xko6e25e.png) (reputation...)

One of my biggest problems is, `columnText.getYLine()` returns the lowest position in the "origin" column even if the text flows over to the next.
I looked through the examples on the iText site and all results on stackoverflow for "itext column" plus some blogs but did not find any solution to my problem, other than [printing each article in a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185423/how-to-skip-text-insertion-point-to-the-next-column-using-itext). A concise description of the problem in a few words would help me search myself as English isn't my first language.

#### additional info

This is part of the report generation in a telemedicine project. A page template is filled by a web front end. There are several post processing steps e.g. attaching images of ECG output. These need a high pixel density to be readable, which is why I use iText (afaik pdfbox scales without taking the density into consideration). Some time ago the physicians noticed they had to insert more text than there's space on one page. So they wanted the overflow in an appendix. I could use another lib. The importance is on high readability on paper and a licence like (l)gpl/apache/... The white space results in more pages hence lessens the overview and wastes paper.

Answer (score 0):

The `setKeepTogether()` method isn't supposed to work in combination with `ColumnText`. As documented in my book (the one shown in my avatar), the `ColumnText` class can be used in [similation mode](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=140) to finetune the layout.

The idea is that you define the location of your content in a trial-and-error process. First you add content and you invoke `go(true)`; This will *consume* the content in your column, but will not add any content to your document. You can use this to discover how many lines have been written (`getLinesWritten()`), to check if all the content could be rendered (`hasMoreText()`), and so on.

Suppose that you find out that all the text can be written using the available space, you add the content to the column once more, change the Y-position to its original value, and add the column for real: `go();`

If there's content left in the column, you should create a new column, add the content anew and then make a decision. Change the position of the column and `go();` If there's content left, but the content can be broken in two parts, change the Y-position and `go()`; then change the position of the column and invoke `go()` once more to render the remainder of the content in a different column.

You'll find different `ColumnText` examples in [chapter 3](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=3).