# How do I determine column number using itext 7

Tags: itext7

I have created documents using itext 7 and its ColumnDocumentRenderer.  I would like to force some text into the last column.  By "last column" I mean for example if I have a single page defined by ColumnDocumentRenderer to have 3 columns but I only have one column of text, I still want column 3 to contain my forced value.  So I suppose (presupposing a solution, others appreciated) that I would need mechanisms to know the column number I'm in and to force a column break.  Since StackOverflow wants this in the form of a question, (a) what are these mechanisms? and (b) what are alternative approaches?

Question [How to skip text insertion point to the next column using iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185423/how-to-skip-text-insertion-point-to-the-next-column-using-itext) apparently asks a similar question but apparently is using an earlier release of itext; mine has no ColumnText that I can find.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'd create my own renderer. Keep track of the column as done in the [documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement), more specifically, I'd overwrite the `updateCurrentArea()` method and expose the `currentAreaNumber`. I'd check that number before adding the content that goes into the third column and add as many `AreaBreak` objects as needed. Note: for some reason the `currentAreaNumber` variable is `private`. I'm tempted to make it `protected`.

Comment: I very much appreciate the link to the documentation.  I followed various links through the itext site but never found the documentation specific to itext7.  thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was answering from my phone yesterday, but now that I have access to a computer, I changed `ColumnDocumentRenderer` like this:

```
public class ColumnDocumentRenderer extends DocumentRenderer {

    protected Rectangle[] columns;
    protected int nextAreaNumber;

    public ColumnDocumentRenderer(Document document, Rectangle[] columns) {
        super(document);
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public ColumnDocumentRenderer(Document document, boolean immediateFlush, Rectangle[] columns) {
        super(document, immediateFlush);
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutArea updateCurrentArea(LayoutResult overflowResult) {
        if (overflowResult != null && overflowResult.getAreaBreak() != null && overflowResult.getAreaBreak().getType() != AreaBreakType.NEXT_AREA) {
            nextAreaNumber = 0;
        }
        if (nextAreaNumber % columns.length == 0) {
            super.updateCurrentArea(overflowResult);
        }
        return (currentArea = new LayoutArea(currentPageNumber, columns[nextAreaNumber++ % columns.length].clone()));
    }

    public int getNextAreaNumber() {
        return nextAreaNumber;
    }
}
```

The change will be in iText 7.0.1, but you can use this code in your own renderer.

You can now use this renderer like this:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fos);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf);

    float offSet = 36;
    float gutter = 23;
    float columnWidth = (PageSize.A4.getWidth() - offSet * 2) / 3 - gutter * 2;
    float columnHeight = PageSize.A4.getHeight() - offSet * 2;
    Rectangle[] columns = {
        new Rectangle(offSet, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight),
        new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth + gutter, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight),
        new Rectangle(offSet + 2 * (columnWidth + gutter), offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight)};
    ColumnDocumentRenderer renderer = new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns);
    document.setRenderer(renderer);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
    }
    while (renderer.getNextAreaNumber() % 3 != 0)
        document.add(new AreaBreak());
    document.add(new Paragraph("Third column"));
    document.add(new AreaBreak());
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
    }
    while (renderer.getNextAreaNumber() % 3 != 0)
        document.add(new AreaBreak());
    document.add(new Paragraph("Third column"));
    document.add(new AreaBreak());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
    }
    while (renderer.getNextAreaNumber() % 3 != 0)
        document.add(new AreaBreak());
    document.add(new Paragraph("Third column"));
    document.close();

}
```

The first column has index 0 and the next area number is 1, the second column has index 1 and the next area number is 2, and so on.

This means that you can check for and go to the third column on a page like this.

```
while (renderer.getNextAreaNumber() % 3 != 0)
    document.add(new AreaBreak());
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to decouple the new `ColumnDocumentRenderer` method from implementation details, have it return the *current* area number, and name it `getAreaNumber`? After all usually an user will want to know which column he is in and not which is the next one. (Yes, it's easy to deduce one from the other, but having a method for getting the current column to me is more intuitive than having to use one for getting the next one.)

Comment: I thought about this, and I had the same idea, but then I found some arguments that made me decide to go for the `nextAreaNumber`. I already forgot those arguments, but I remember they were related to the effect of a page break.